# How to use tab to go to a certain input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently when the user presses tab in the `qty` text box it does not tab to the add line image.

I want to add some jQuery in which would make it so that when the user presses the tab key within the `qty` text box it tabs to the add image where the user can click enter.

```
<td> 
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="3" class="txt" style="width: 80px;" />                         
</td>
<td> 
    <input type="image" src="/gfx/btn_addline.jpg" name="Add" value="Add" id="add"/>
</td>
```

Jquery affecting qty:

```
 $("#qty").keydown(function (event) {
            //alert(event.keyCode);
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $("#add").click();
                return false;
            }
        });
   $("#qty").keydown(function (event) {
            // Allow only backspace and delete
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? How will the user input a value into qty?

Comment: @Isiscode when the OP says 'click', I think they mean 'press key' - ie tab is the tab key.

Comment: the user will enter their qty then tab to the add image and click enter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you should just use the `tabindex` attribute, which doesn't require any JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1"> <!--First input-->
<input type="text" tabindex="2"> <!--Press tab, you will end up here-->
```

**Update** (see comments)

If you already use `tabindex` to control tab order elsewhere on your page, just use higher indexes here. For example, if indexes 1-10 are used on other elements, use 11 and 12 here:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="11"> <!--First input-->
<input type="text" tabindex="12"> <!--Press tab, you will end up here-->
```

**Update 2** (see updated question)

You are preventing the tab key from doing anything in your `keydown` event handler. Change to the following (add another condition that checks for the tab key):

```
if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
}
```

This will work without the need for `tabindex`, assuming your two inputs are in order in your code and there are no inputs between them. If there are, use `tabindex` as well.

As a side note, you should use [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of `keyCode`, since jQuery uses it to normalise browser inconsistencies.

Comment: i cant use this as im using this in another part of the page

Comment: @Beginner - Just use different indexes. For example, if you use 1-10 somewhere else, start at 11 here.

Comment: @beginner You can still use this, just make the image tabindex 1 higher than the textbox.

Comment: still not working, it may be to do with the jquery already controlling what goes into qty, i will update my question...

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do the trick

```
$("#qty").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode=='9') { //9 is the tab key
    $("#add").focus();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#qty").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode=='9') { //9 is the tab key
    $("#add").focus();
    $("#add").select();
  }
});
```

Can you try focus and select together for Image field.